# Python WMI modules requires Internet access?

Tags: python, windows, wmi

Does the WMI Python module require an Internet connection? I'm trying to connect between two systems that are connected to the same hub, and WMI works when there's an internet connection but doesn't when there is no internet access. I've read through Golden's tutorials and nowhere does it say anything about internet. Just want confirmation, thanks!

Comment: You might consider seeing what (attempted) network traffic is happening with, say, Wireshark.

Comment: It should not need it to my knowledge

Comment: interesting... @icktoofay, I'll give wireshark a try, see if it brings up anything that I'm not seeing. thanks!

Comment: @MikeDriscoll , that's what I thought, which is why it's very strange that the only way it's working is with an internet connection. Could it possibly be a Windows setting that I'm neglecting?

Comment: @atf Try using WMI only on one of the machines that's disconnected from the internet. Basically, do some local tests. I wonder if it doesn't work via LANs as I'm sure I've used it on my laptop with the wi-fi off in the past.